# Django messages.success giving TypeError 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I am using Django==1.6 and I am getting some weird errors with django messages

The error im getting is:

```
TypeError 'tuple' object is not callable
```

The problem line is reportedly:

```
        messages.success(request, 'whatever message I am trying to display')
```

Im getting this error from 4 different views. Some of these views are in different apps.

```
 in some_app.views
 ...
 from django.contrib import messages
 ...

 def foo(request):
    ...
    if not worker.profile_complete and worker.is_profile_complete:
        worker.profile_complete = True
        worker.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your profile is now complete')
        success_url = reverse('worker_complete')




 in some_other_app.views
 ...
 from django.contrib import messages
 ...

 def bar(request):
    ....
    form = VerificationForm(data=request.REQUEST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.user.verification.code == form.cleaned_data['code'].upper():
            verification.verified = timezone.now()
            verification.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been verified via SMS')
```

This error is stumping me. I can only reproduce it sometimes on the production server. I have been unable to reproduce it locally.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Traceback available here: http://pastebin.com/efTW1EhP

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure you have not overwritten `messages.success` with a tuple somewhere in your codebase. For example, you might have done:

```
messages.success = (request, 'success message')
```

This could be anywhere in your project, not just in the views you have shown above.